# Fast boot via Live DVD

Tags: boot

I create a ISO from my UBUNTU 16.04 and burn a Live DVD. But, is very slow. From start to finish the boot process, 20 minutes. And in the middle of the boot, there are a question about if I want install or only run Ubuntu via DVD.

My computer: Acer, 2GB RAM, 160GB HDD.

I need a Live CD to run a especific program, and that program is in the ISO image.
After 20 minutes all works fine, but 20 minutes.... It is so much time.

How to create a Live DVD, without interruptions in the boot process and fast in the boot process?

Comment: DVD disks are rather slow. A *fast* USB 3 pendrive is much faster. Would that be an option for you? Will you use the drive in one computer or in two or more computers?

Comment: Another option is to run your specific program in Lubuntu, which is smaller (less program code to read from the install media), maybe 60% compared to standard Ubuntu. You can also create a custom system from the Ubuntu mini.iso or Ubuntu Server iso file and add only the absolutely necessary program packages for this application. Then the size could be much smaller than Lubuntu (and it would boot much faster).

Comment: If you're normally running a different operating system it may be easier and faster to use an Ubuntu installation inside a virtual machine than to reboot every time you want to use that one program.

Comment: In this case only DVD-Rom. I can´t use pendrives.

Comment: Will you use the drive in one computer or in two or more computers? Can you create a custom system from the Ubuntu mini.iso or Ubuntu Server iso file and add only the absolutely necessary program packages for this application?

Comment: Who to customize a mini.iso? I need run a Java application in the DVD-Rom. Who to put Java in this ISO file?